# memory allocation in c++ done by compiler or run time system

Tags: c++

```
class test{
int n;
public(){
n = 10;
}
};
```

when we create object :

```
test t ;             // compiler will call the constructor.
```

```
test *tt = new t1(); // in this case who will call the constructor
                     // compiler or will be called
```

by run time os ?
why i am thiking compiler , because at this time all the information are available to compiler regarding object creation.
then i heard that all dynamic allocation will be done at run time with keyword new, malloc.
please help in clearing this doubt!
many thanks!

Comment: That's not valid C++.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time, the compiler will generate machine code that allocates the memory. The generated code will likely call a library function (which in turn may call an OS function), then call the appropriate constructor, etc.

The actual allocation will then happen at runtime, when the generated code is being executed.

Comment: Note: this is the answer for `new t1`. The first case is almost the same, except that it's unlikely a library function needs to be called for `test t`. It's probably on the stack, but that stack too is OS-provided.